# Why the solution set of the equation $\sqrt{x-1}(x^2-1)$ doesn’t include $-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why the solution set of the equation $\sqrt{x-1}(x^2-1)$ doesn’t include $-1$. If I take $x=-1$ I get $2i\times 0$ which equals $0$ and hence $-1$ should also be considered the solution (along with $+1$)

Comment: Kindly request you to accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\sqrt{x-1}(x^2-1)$ is defined so as to take only real values : in other words, its domain does not include $-1$, for which $\sqrt{x-1}$ does not take a real value (and therefore, it cannot be multiplied by $x^2-1$ even if $x^2-1 = 0$, because we don't remain in the domain of reals, so a priori do not know that multiplication is defined there.)

Therefore, $-1$ cannot be considered to be a root of the equation.

Comment: Firstly sorry I read your answer just now. Now my question is then how do we get to know that when to use complex numbers and when not(for-example when do we write $\sqrt{-1}=i$)

Comment: Right : See, $\sqrt{-1} = i$ is not really part of the *definition* of the complex square root : it has a more complicated definition , something only studied much later (I gauge your level as being in high school). The square root, when used in this context, means the *real* square root.For domain applications, we stick to reals, unless specified otherwise (almost never). Complex numbers (and the definition $i = \sqrt {-1}$) are not used in domain problems, but are used in computations involving complex numbers (simplifying complex number expressions etc.)

Comment: So you mean to say that whenever an equation is given(whose solution we need to find) prior to solving we assume that the equation needs to be solved only within the domain of real numbers and will be soved within the domain of complex numbers only if it is specified to do so. Have I understood it right ? **PLEASE reply.** .

Comment: Correct, you have said it right. It is so important that I will put it in to the main answer.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your given function is  taken as real valued  function.. 
hence defined for only real values, Domain of the given function
 $$\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x\ge 1\}$$